# Metropolis Hastings Proposal Distribution

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

[image]

I am trying to sample from a bivariate normal distribution given above. If the proposal distribution is q(theta|theta prime) and theta prime = theta + U, where U is uniformly distributed over [a,b], what are the conditions on a and b?

Comment: The question does not really make sense since $\theta$ is multidimensional while $U$ is unidimensional.